# Entity Framework 6: Problem with many to many relationship

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework-6

I started with a tutorial, where I created classes :

```
namespace SamuraiApp.Domain
{
    public class Battle
    {
        public int BattleId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Samurai> Samurais = new List<Samurai>();
    }
}
```

and

```
namespace SamuraiApp.Domain
{
    public class Samurai
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Quote> Quotes { get; set; } = new List<Quote>();
        public List<Battle> Battles { get; set; } = new List<Battle>();
    }
}
```

and dbcontext

```
 public class SamuraiContext:DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Samurai> Samurais { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Quote> Quotes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Battle> Battles { get; set; }
          protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source= (localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog=SamuraiAppData");
            // si on a sqlLite on va écrire  optionsBuilder.UseSqlLite("<chaine de connexion sqlite>")

        }

    }
```

I thought that entityFramework6 alone interprets the many-to-many relationships and generates the intermediate table BattleSamurai, but the generation of the base did not take into account this relationship (see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMSdc.png)).

Do you have any comments, please?

Comment: The many-to-many relationship is a common scenario in database design, but it can also be more complex than this basic example. You may need to consider additional factors such as cascading deletes, unique constraints, and other business rules when designing your database schema. Please feel free to let know if you have any question.

Answer (score 1):

Add `public int BattleId { get; set; }` to `Samurai` and `public int SamuraiId { get; set; }` to `Battle`.

To make sure you can see in migration if `Samurai` has foreign key to `Battle` and vice versa.

Comment: I had the same result ,
 
it always considers the relation as one to many, in both directions, but it did not create a third table for a relation many to many

Answer (score 0):

I am following [this article](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx#:%7E:text=Note%3A%20EF%20automatically%20creates%20a,and%20the%20suffix%20%27s%27.) about Many-to-Many relationships in EF.

According to it, the code should look like this (Please note that I can't see the Quote class, probably, you have to refactor that one too at Samurai class to match ICollection):

```
namespace SamuraiApp.Domain
{
    public class Battle
    {
        public Battle() 
        {
             this.Samurais = new HashSet<Samurai>();
        }
        public int BattleId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Samurai> Samurais {get; set;}
    }
}

namespace SamuraiApp.Domain
{
    public class Samurai
    {
        public Samurai()
        {
           this.Battles = new HashSet<Battle>();
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Quote> Quotes { get; set; } = new List<Quote>();
        public ICollection<Battle> Battles { get; set; };
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not put the Quote class in my question since the relationship is one to many, and it was created correctly. 
I added what you put but I got this error






'Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<SamuraiApp.Domain.Samurai>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<SamuraiApp.Domain.Samurai>' SamuraiApp.Domain D:\Users\we\source\repos\SamuraiApp\SamuraiApp.Domain\Battle.cs    13  Active'

Comment: Then you must have left a = new List<>() At row 13, no? what does it look like now?